# Unable to read a text file using `std.file.readText(fileName)` in Visual D (throws strange exception)

Tags: file, exception, character-encoding, text-files, d

The exception details are:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF7B11A7F40 in mutation_lib.exe: 0xC0000096: Privileged instruction.
```

And it occurs at this line in the standard library source:

```
void[] read(R)(R name, size_t upTo = size_t.max)
if (isInputRange!R && isSomeChar!(ElementEncodingType!R) && !isInfinite!R &&
    !isConvertibleToString!R)
{
    static if (isNarrowString!R && is(immutable ElementEncodingType!R == immutable char))
        return readImpl(name, name.tempCString!FSChar(), upTo);  // (THIS LINE TRIGGERS EXCEPTION)
    else
        return readImpl(null, name.tempCString!FSChar(), upTo);
}
```

The string I pass in is "prog9.asm" and it is a file located in the same directory as the Dlanguage EXE.

I checked the encoding of the file and it is pure ANSI / ASCII.

A minimal exception-throwing example is this:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.file;

void main()
{
   while (true) {
      writeln("Enter a .asm file name: ");
      auto asmFileName = readln();
      auto asmSource = readText(asmFileName);
   }
}
```

---

Update.  I've tracked it down somewhat.  If I create a new `test.txt` in windows explorer in the same dir as EXE.  And I pass in the string "test.txt" literally (not using a string variable), then it works.

So how can one parse a string from command line and then pass it into `readText()` is the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.  You need to strip the newlines from `asmFileName` before treating it as a file name:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.file;
import std.string;

void main()
{
   while (true) {
      writeln("Enter a .asm file name: ");
      string asmFileName = readln();
      asmFileName = strip(asmFileName);
      auto asmSource = readText(asmFileName);
   }
}
```